# Duplicate name "app" passed to addEntry(): entries must be unique

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

Hello I try to install sylius BootstrapTheme for my project and I have little problem when i try to install this. If need more code or code of other files for find the problem talk me

/themes/BootstrapTheme/webpack.config.js

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
  .setOutputPath('public/bootstrap-theme')
  .setPublicPath('/bootstrap-theme')
  .addEntry('app', './themes/BootstrapTheme/assets/app.js')
  .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableSassLoader()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction());

const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.name = 'bootstrapTheme';

module.exports = config;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const bootstrapTheme = require('./themes/BootstrapTheme/webpack.config');
module.exports = [bootstrapTheme];
// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    //.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

but when I when I run yarn encore production I have this error :

Duplicate name "app" passed to addEntry(): entries must be unique.

what I can do for leave this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear **Duplicate name "app" passed to addEntry(): entries must be unique.**.

In your `/themes/BootstrapTheme/webpack.config.js` you have:

```
.addEntry('app', './themes/BootstrapTheme/assets/app.js')
```

And, in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
```

I'm far from being an expert in Webpack but I believe you could delete the second one, as now you are using BootstrapTheme's one. If you need both the scripts, you could change the name of the entry in your `webpack.config.js` to something else, like:

```
.addEntry('someName', './assets/js/app.js')
```

Then you add your new tag to the twig file:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('someName') }}
//the rest of your js code, if you have
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try to just remove the line `.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')` from your `webpack.config.js`, keeping the one that came with BoostrapTheme. If nothing breaks, the job is done.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of what you can try next